# Alter database query with variables using Python

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I am trying to execute below SQL query by introducing 2 variables in Python but getting error,

Original Query:

```
ALTER DATABASE db1 MODIFY (SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'DW300');
```

I want to use variables for db1 and 'DW300'. I have tried below statement in Python and got error.

```
dwu = 'DW100'
sqlpool = 'db1'
cursor.execute("""ALTER DATABASE ? MODIFY (SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = ?) """, (sqlpool, dwu))

Error: pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P1'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use sqlite and it accepts this answe.

try the use of fstrings

```py
f"""Alter Database {sqlpool} modify (service objective = {dwu}) """
```